# Using showSuccessMessage and showErrorMessage functions in prestashop

Tags: javascript, ajax, prestashop

I'm using the showSuccessMessage() and showErrorMessage() functions in ajax on the prestashop platform, but I can't find any information about the origin of these functions anywhere.

Does anyone have this knowledge? What are they part of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are just aliases to other jQuery plugin $.growl which PrestaShop uses from the admin panel. You can find their definition in the js/admin.js file.

See source on [github](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/9f62ffc549de9c3c3d9d7d9c7579422956d8d8ce/js/admin.js#LL630C1-L642C1)

You can read about growl jquery plugin [here](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/)